meaning of inform

The public’s concerns were over future access to travel advice and information, assistance for disabled people, safety at understaffed stations, and consequences for the less digitally savvy and the digitally excluded. But the passionate backlash also underlined a widespread sense that railway stations must be more than arid transit zones, to be navigated solely through the use of a smartphone. Combined with a reformed fares and ticketing system, that insight should now inform a positive approach to reinvigorating England’s railways and attracting more people on to trains.
---The Guardian view on England’s train stations: make them part of a rail renaissance

I failed to find a suitable explanation for "inform" here in the dictionary. Does it mean influencing something? It seems that makes no sense. In addition, How can I grammatically understand the infinitive here? Is the 'to'-infinitive used to show an unpleasant result? What is navigated solely through the use of a smartphone?

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inform definition 2.  Basically, this insight should guide, or give a specific character to the approach.

So, "Does it mean influencing something?" Well yeah, kind of. The insight should "influence," or at least serve as an informational foundation for, "a positive approach."

Inform takes M+W sense 2:

2a. to give character or essence to


the principles which inform modern teaching


b. to be the characteristic quality of


the compassion that informs her work

The passage means that insight (with a reformed fares and ticketing system)
should now be the characteristic quality of a positive approach to reinvigorating England’s railways ...
It is railway stations. Railway stations must be more than (meaning must not be just) transit zones to be navigated solely through the use of a smartphone.

Thanks, @Michael Harvey.  I've been typing so many transitives (as in transitive verbs) that the autocorrect feature remembers my favourite word.
